# How to keep an anciant form saved with new version in ORBEON?

Tags: forms, xhtml, field, orbeon, savechanges

How to keep an anciant form saved with new version.
I have saved a form in our application.this is a screenshot in below for my form in builder and Runner:
[image]
[image]
After that i added a new field using (form-builder),but when i opened this form saved, i didn't find the field added.
this is a screenshot form my new version of Form:[image]
and this is the result that i had :
[image]

**EDIT**

@Avernet,i used the CRUD API and i followed steps using two methods :

1. Retrieve the xml of a form by imposing the most recent version number:

   - Create a form with an earlier version : test with docId=fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e and  version =1
   - run this command with curl (curl -v -k -H
     "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version: 2" 
     http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e/data.xml)

     =>result 400 bad request.

   => If I put the old version 1 instead of 2, there is no error.
2. Create an empty test form with the latest version and fill it with
   the form created with the old version

   - run this command with curl (curl -v -k -H
     "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version: 1"
     http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e/data.xml >>myData)
     =>xml file save to a directory
   - save an empty test form with the new version (documentId =
     40239f94e49538db4e94e4f60ad7b4f312c23f3e)
   - run this command with curl ( curl -v -k -d @mydata.xml -H
     "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version:
     2" -X PUT
     http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/40239f94e49538db4e94e4f60ad7b4f312c23f3e/data.xml)

     =>result 500 Internal server error

This is a stacktrace when the error was occured:

> |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |Fatal error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.                               |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-xml-submission.xpl                                            |reading processor output      | 111|
>   |Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·|
>   |element=                                                                        |
>   |name   =data                                                                                                          |
>   |ref    =instance                                                                                                      |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-xml-submission.xpl                                            |reading processor output      | 102|
>   |Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·|
>   |element=                                                                     |
>   |name   =data                                                                                                          |
>   |id     =raw-instance                                                                                                  |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |:/Users/fkammoun/AppData/Local/Temp/upload__5a2c8fe_15fbb88e967__8000_00000000.tmp|                              |   1|
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
>   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLParsing$ErrorHandler         |fatalError                    |XMLParsing.java               | 221|
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper      |fatalError                    |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner               |reportFatalError              |                              |    |
>   |.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher|dispatch                      |                              |    |
>   |n.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl|scanDocument                  |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse                         |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse                         |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser             |parse                         |                              |    |
>   |orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser     |parse                         |                              |    |
>   |processor.generator.URLGenerator$URLResourceHandler|readXML                       |URLGenerator.java             |1042|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$1  |readImpl                      |URLGenerator.java             | 545|
>   |essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
>   |ssor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$InternalTopOutput$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 535|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeParents                |PipelineProcessor.java        | 696|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|access$400                    |PipelineProcessor.java        |  60|
>   |cessor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$InternalTopOutput|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        | 531|
>   |essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 266|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.IdentityProcessor$1       |readImpl                      |IdentityProcessor.java        |  33|
>   |essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
>   |orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 679|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|access$000                    |PipelineProcessor.java        |  60|
>   |g.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        |  91|
>   |essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
>   |processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor$1|readImpl                      |ConcreteChooseProcessor.java  | 126|
>   |essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
>   |org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
>   |orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, and if you are using a database [for which Orbeon Forms supports versioning](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/db-support.html), then Orbeon Forms even keeps track of which version of the form definition is used when filling out new form, and uses that (possibly old) version again when you come back to edit that piece of data.

This is done because it is possible for a new version of a form definition to be incompatible with a previous version. In general, it is possible to migrate data from an old version of a form definition to a new version, but Orbeon Forms doesn't know how to do this migration automatically. If this is something you need, you will need to do it at the database level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes we need to migrate data from an old version of a form definition to a new version : in order to save time (and money) in our daily activity, we want to be able to reuse previous saved data (e.g. same order, same client, … ), by duplicating an existing file saved with Orbeon. In case of the form definition has changed (bug fix, enhancement, …), we want to reuse the « old » data but with the new form version. So can you be more precise on your suggestion « you will need to do it at the database level. » ? Did you think about XSL transformation ?.

Comment: I think that your best bet is to use the [CRUD API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/crud.html) to read the data you want to update, before you make the changes to the XML and write them back using that same CRUD API. When writing, you can set the `Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version` to the new version of the you're updating the data to. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you Avernet for your response, I'm going to try it and i'll tell you if it works.